# Imperfections dans mon français

Tags: code-golf, natural-language

To conjugate a verb in *l'imparfait*, one needs to perform the following steps:

1. Find the "stem" of the word; this is achieved by omitting the `-ons` from the nous-conjugated form of the word. For example, *vivre* is *nous vivons*; removing `-ons` from *vivons* yields `viv-`.
2. Take the stem and add an appropriate ending, according to the subject. Here are the endings:

   ```
   je         -ais
   tu         -ais
   il/elle    -ait

   nous       -ions
   vous       -iez
   ils/elles  -aient
   ```

**Objective** Given a verb and a subject, output the imperfect form of that verb with respect to the subject. The input format can be in any format convenient to your language. Your submission can either be a program, snippet, or function. (Note that the verb does not have to be a real verb.)

You can assume that the verb is a regular verb, i.e, items like *avoir* would be treated as an `-ir` verb, not an irregular one. The only verb you have to quantify as irregular is *être*; it is conjugated as such:

```
j'étais
tu étais
il/elle était

nous étions
vous étiez
ils/elles étaient
```

Here are the conjugations for `-er`, `-re`, and `-ir` verbs in the nous forms

```
-ER => (e)ons           ; e is added after a 'g'
-RE => ons
-IR => issons
```

Anything that does not end with such does not have to be handled.

(Note that *je* merges with the next vowel, if there is one. E.g., `je acheter -> j'achetais`. `h` will be considered a vowel for our purposes.)

## Example IOs

```
input: tu vivre
output: tu vivais

input: elles nager
output: elles nageaient

input: je morter
output: je mortais     ; incorrect in real life, but correct for our purposes

input: vous finir
output: vous finissiez

input: il croire
output: il croiait

input: nous jouer
output: nous jouions
```

## Bonuses

- -5N bytes for all `N` extra irregular verb handled.
- -10% if you *also* output every conjugation of the verb in the imperfect tense.

---

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Does `je habiter` become `j' habite` or `j'habite`?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Either is fine.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ For the -10% bonus, does the input still need to have the pronoun, or can it just be the verb?

Comment: `Morter` doesn't exist, I assume you are referring to `to die` which is `mourir`, which would yield `je mourais` which is actually correct.

Comment: @Fatalize I was referring to `morter`. It's technically incorrect because its not a word.

Comment: Incidentally, `il croiait` is incorrect as well (should be `il croyait`).

Comment: @Arnauld the challenge doesn't handle irregulars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Processing, 342-10%(bonus) = 307.8

I have created a function. To call the function, include the pronoun as the first parameter and the verb as the second. For example, `a("je","habiter")`

Please note that my program conjugates the verb for all the pronouns, so that is how I got the 10% bonus.

```
void a(String a,String b){String[]e={"ais","ais","ait","ait","ions","iez","aient","aient"},p={"je","tu","il","elle","nous","vous","ils","elles"};if("aehiou".contains(b.charAt(0)+""))p[0]="j'";for(String i:p)println(i+" "+b.substring(0,b.length()-2)+(b.endsWith("ger")?"e":b.endsWith("ir")?"iss":"")+e[java.util.Arrays.asList(p).indexOf(i)]);}
```

Readable form:

```
void a(String a,String b){
  String[]e={"ais","ais","ait","ait","ions","iez","aient","aient"},p={"je","tu","il","elle","nous","vous","ils","elles"};
  if("aehiou".contains(b.charAt(0)+""))p[0]="j'";
  for(String i:p)
    println(i+" "+b.substring(0,b.length()-2)+(b.endsWith("ger")?"e":b.endsWith("ir")?"iss":"")+e[java.util.Arrays.asList(p).indexOf(i)]);
}
```

Output (for `a("je", "habiter")`)

```
j' habitais
tu habitais
il habitait
elle habitait
nous habitions
vous habitiez
ils habitaient
elles habitaient
```

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Yes! Yes! Yes! My first victory in code-golf! Yes! Yes! [clears throat] @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ Thank you.

Comment: Not all verbs with a leading h will elide the pronoun. Only those with a silent h. Counter examples are haïr (je hais) (irregular anyway), hacher, haleter, halter, hérisser and many more.

You also miss the verbs ending in -cer, where the "nous form" becomes -çons.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>366</s> <s>362</s> 352 bytes

```
s#v=m++g++d++t
 where
 m|v=="être"="ét"|i/="rio"&&i/="erd"&&i/="eri"=r 2 v|otherwise=r 3 v
 g=if(last m=='g'&&head t/='i')then"e"else""
 d|init i=="ri"="iss"|i=="eri"="y"|otherwise=""
 t|s=="je"||s=="tu"="ais"|elem s["il","elle","on"]="ait"|s=="nous"="ions"|s=="vous"="iez"|s=="ils"||s=="elles"="aient"
 r i=reverse.drop i.reverse
 i=take 3$reverse v
```

You can compile this in ghci and use it like so `"je"#"choisir"` to get `"choisissais"`.

This code works with some irregular verbs. It can conjugate *croire* (*je croyais*, *tu croyais*…) or *prendre* as well as all its derivatives (*apprendre*, *comprendre*, etc.).

I couldn't find a short way to conjugate other verbs ending in -ire (such as *lire*, *rire*, *dire*, etc.) or in -dre (such as *craindre*, *soudre*, etc.).

Comment: Shouldn't it be 352 bytes because of the `ê` and `é`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php), <s>389</s> <s>385</s> <s>383</s> <s>382</s> <s>352.7</s> 443-10%(bonus) = 398.7 bytes

Byte count reduced thanks to @PeterTaylor and @Fatalize

Please note that my program conjugates the verb for all the pronouns, so that is how I got the 10% bonus.

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){String[]e={"ais","ais","ait","ait","ions","iez","aient","aient"},p={"je","tu","il","elle","nous","vous","ils","elles"},w=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");if("aehiou".contains(w[1].charAt(0)+""))p[0]="j'";for(String i:p)System.out.println(i+" "+w[1].substring(0,w[1].length()-2)+(w[1].endsWith("ger")?"e":w[1].endsWith("ir")?"iss":"")+e[java.util.Arrays.asList(p).indexOf(i)]);}}
```

Readable form (still quite messy):

```
 1| class A{
 2|   public static void main(String[]a){
 3|     String[]e={"ais","ais","ait","ait","ions","iez","aient","aient"};
 4|     String[]p={"je","tu","il","elle","nous","vous","ils","elles"};
 5|     String[]w=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");
 6|     if("aehiou".contains(w[1].charAt(0)+""))p[0]="j'";
 7|     for(String i: p) {
 8|       System.out.print(i+" "+w[1].substring(0,w[1].length()-2)+(w[1].endsWith("ger")?"e":w[1].endsWith("ir")?"iss":"")+e[java.util.Arrays.asList(p).indexOf(i)]);
 9|     }
10|   }
11| }
```

Explanation:

```
Lines 3-4: Initialisation of arrays.
Line    5: Read a line as input and split it into words
Line    6: Shorten the `je` to `j'` in presence of a succeeding vowel or a `h`.
Line    7: Create a for-loop iterating through all of the pronouns .
Line    8: Conjugate the verb(remove the ending from the infinite form of the verb and add ending accordingly) and print the result, along with the pronoun.
```

### (Old Version) 393-10% = 352.7 bytes

Please note also that my old program does not obey with the new rule about the `je` merging into `j'`.

```
class A{public static void main(String[]a){String[]e={"ais","ais","ait","ait","ions","iez","aient","aient"},p={"je","tu","il","elle","nous","vous","ils","elles"},w=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine().split(" ");for(String i:p)System.out.println(i+" "+w[1].substring(0,w[1].length()-2)+(w[1].endsWith("ger")?"e":w[1].endsWith("ir")?"iss":"")+e[java.util.Arrays.asList(p).indexOf(i)]);}}
```

Comment: Why do you have both `k` and `l`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Gee, thanks for spotting that one!

Comment: You have a useless space here: `w[1].substring(0, w[1].length()-2)`

Comment: @Fatalize I have removed the useless space in my latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>258-10% = 232.2</strike> 223-10% = 200.7

Huge thanks to @WW for saving me 35 bytes!

```python
def t(x,y):
 z=y[-2:];y=y[:-2];y+='e'*(y[-1]=='g');y+='iss'*(z=='ir')
 return[('j'+"e'"[y[0]in'aeiouh']+' tu il elle nous vous ils elles').split()[i]+' '+y+'ais ais ait ait ions iez aient aient'.split()[i]for i in range(8)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BboMwDIbvPIXVi5PRTlt3mZh4kigHppriKXVQEqqGl2cBLpPWgy37@/3r95jT4OVjWS7UQ1KPY9ZNBXObzenc2K9chuZ0LkPdIuGLKvzdti1eUW@MYyx0LoQD6goCpSmIUfiD9YHwYLJ5syzYEftpQFsjpAnYATlHIH6KcF8bu7ihiPo1jo6T0obXa6xzjR1H2CttxV6KheaykKS94x9f7wMwsEDo5ErqU9tlDCxJJYV7yhF7lvVlXf1Thu6bEz3XRpJLoKfSbc1aXcsv)

Comment: You can use a `split` to compress your lists a little more.  Also using `;` can help you to avoid some of the indentation.

Comment: You also don't need parens around your conditionals in the `if`s.

Comment: Lastly you can use boolean multiplication to get around two of the `if`s altogether.  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BboMwDIbvPIXVi5PRTlt3majyJCgHppriChyUhKnh5WkAaZf1YMv/98vy7zHFzsnXslyphagex6SrAgaDd4I4AfdAfU8gbgrwuzbuw4YCvoex56j0ZTapPp0re0l5qE7nPJQGCd9U5p/WGLyh3hiHkOmcCXvUBXALqf6wLNgQu6nDasjSHO54KMBTnLxAPdRsSwQsU4kNB9grbsVOciSasyCJe/8LlvegdR4YWMA3ciP1re0yepaoosL9jSO2LGscXfxzuuaHI732RpKrp5fWsN5at5Yn "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Your submission seems to put a space after `j'`, which doesn't seem to match the spec.

Comment: @WW Thanks! and in the comments of the main post the OP says "j' " with a space is fine

Comment: In that case [here's a shorter version](https://tio.run/##bY7BboMwDIbvPIXVi5PRTlt3mZh4kigHppriKXVQEqqGl2cBLpPWgy37@/3r95jT4OVjWS7UQ1KPY9ZNBXObzenc2K9chuZ0LkPdIuGLKvzdti1eUW@MYyx0LoQD6goCpSmIUfiD9YHwYLJ5syzYEftpQFsjpAnYATlHIH6KcF8bu7ihiPo1jo6T0obXa6xzjR1H2CttxV6KheaykKS94x9f7wMwsEDo5ErqU9tlDCxJJYV7yhF7lvVlXf1Thu6bEz3XRpJLoKfSbc1aXcsv "Python 3 – Try It Online")